# EXCEL VBA: How to set a password to another VBProject programmaticaly

Tags: excel, password-protection, sendkeys, vbe, vba

I have created a vba code that creates a new .xlms file, adding some code to that file and then my problem is that i cannot protect the VBPoject of that new file. Instead, i wrongly password protect the current VBProject (not the new one, that i want).
Here is my code:

```
Sub Create_xlsm_File()

Dim VBProj As VBIDE.VBProject
Dim VBComp As VBIDE.VBComponent
Dim CodeMod As VBIDE.CodeModule
Dim LineNum As Long
Dim ModuleName As String
Dim NewProcAsString As String
Dim myDir1 As String
Dim FileName1 As String
Dim FolderPath1 As String
Dim FilePath1 As String
Dim Pass1 As String
Dim SheetName1FileName1 As String
Dim MasterName As String
Dim NoOfSheets As Integer
Dim Newbook1 As Workbook

MasterName = Environ("UserName")
myDir1 = "C:\Users\" & MasterName & "\Desktop"
FileName1 = "LockedVBAProject"
Pass1 = "123"
NoOfSheets = 1
SheetName1FileName1 = "Sh1"
ModuleName = "Module1"
'----Creating and Save File-------------------------------------------
Set Newbook1 = Workbooks.Add
Newbook1.Activate
FilePath1 = myDir1 & "\" & FileName1
Application.SheetsInNewWorkbook = NoOfSheets
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Name = SheetName1FileName1
Newbook1.SaveAs Filename:=FilePath1, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, Password:=Pass1
Workbooks(FileName1).Close False
'----Add the VBA code to the File-------------------------------------
Application.Workbooks.Open (FilePath1), Password:=Pass1
Workbooks(FileName1).Activate
'=====================================================================
'This part is the problem. the SendKeys applied to current project and
' not to the desired "LockedVBAProject"
'=====================================================================
With Application
      '//execute the controls to lock the project\\
      .VBE.CommandBars("Menu Bar").Controls("Tools") _
                  .Controls("VBAProject Properties...").Execute

      '//activate 'protection'\\
      .SendKeys "^{TAB}", True

      '//CAUTION: this either checks OR UNchecks the\\
      '//"Lock Project for Viewing" checkbox, if it's already\\
      '//been locked for viewing, then this will UNlock it\\
      .SendKeys "{ }", True

      '//enter password (password is 123 in this example)\\
      .SendKeys "{TAB}" & "123", True

      '//confirm password\\
      .SendKeys "{TAB}" & "123", True

      '//scroll down to OK key\\
      .SendKeys "{TAB}", True

      '//click OK key\\
      .SendKeys "{ENTER}", True

      'the project is now locked - this takes effect
      'the very next time the book's opened...
End With
'=====================================================================
'=====================================================================
'=====================================================================

Set VBProj = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject
Set VBComp = VBProj.VBComponents.Add(vbext_ct_StdModule)
VBComp.Name = ModuleName
Set VBComp = VBProj.VBComponents("ThisWorkbook")
Set CodeMod = VBComp.CodeModule

With CodeMod
    LineNum = .CreateEventProc("Open", "Workbook")
    LineNum = LineNum + 2
    NewProcAsString = "MsgBox ""Hola !!!"""
    CodeMod.InsertLines LineNum, NewProcAsString
End With

Workbooks(FileName1).Save
Workbooks(FileName1).Close False


ThisWorkbook.Activate

End Sub
```

Can you please help me to select and password protect the desired new "LockedVBAProject" file?
Any other suggestions?
Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: I would like to hear the answer to this, too. I am trying to unlock the VBA code for a Word document from within Excel VBA code, then update the code in the Word doc, then lock it back up again. Using examples like this, I end up inserting the password into the Excel code (not what I wanted). I tried putting a `Public Sub` into the Word doc and running that from Excel, but it seems to get quite confused. Any thoughts???

Answer (score 0):

Since someone like me could stumble upon this post in the future, the solution is simply to activate the corresponding VBProject by using the following:

`set Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject = Application.Workbooks(FileName1).VBProject`

However, the order of the `sendKeys()`-commands does not work (at least for me), so here is the whole thing as a sub:

```
Public Sub lockVBProject(wbName As String, password As String, locked As Boolean)
'set password for another workbooks VBA project via sendKeys method
'adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29937422/excel-vba-how-to-set-a-password-to-another-vbproject-programmaticaly
    
    With Application
        
        'select the appropriate VBProject        
        Set .VBE.ActiveVBProject = .Workbooks(wbName).VBProject
    
        'open project properties
        .VBE.CommandBars(1).FindControl(ID:=2578, recursive:=True).Execute

        'activate tab 'protection'
        .SendKeys "^{TAB}", True
                
        'mark checkbox
        .SendKeys "{TAB}", True
                
        'use space to select checkbox
        .SendKeys "{ }", True
        
        'unmark checkbox
        .SendKeys "{TAB}", True
                
        'enter password
        .SendKeys "{TAB}" & password, True
        
        'confirm password
        .SendKeys "{TAB}" & password, True
                
        'close dialog
        .SendKeys "{ENTER}", True
        
    End With

End Sub
```